# Should I call GC.Collect() in Dispose() method?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, dispose

My example code:

```
using System;
namespace Program
{
    class Test : IDisposable
    {
        public long Loop()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                var t = new Test();
            }
            return GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Memory used: " + GC.GetTotalMemory(false));

            using (var t = new Test())
            {
                long size = t.Loop();
                Console.WriteLine("Memory used: " + size);
            }

            //object "t" and variable "size" cannot be re-used here
            //GC.Collect() should be called automatically

            Console.WriteLine("Memory used: " + GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
        }
    }
}
```

Result was:

> Memory used: 29868
>
> Memory used: 160940
>
> Memory used: 30712

If I remove `GC.Collect()` in `Dispose` method, the result maybe:

> Memory used: 29868
>
> Memory used: 160940
>
> Memory used: 160940

I don't understand why doesn't `GC.Collect()` start automatically after I run the `using` statement?

Can you give me a reason?

And a sub-question: Is it necessary if I wanna call `GC.Collect()` in `Dispose` method?

Comment: You should never call `GC.Collect()` (testing, experimenting etc. excluded)

Comment: IDisposable has nothing to do with the GC heap, it releases *unmanaged* resources.  So you should never do that.

Comment: @HansPassant I mean that:  When an object is unused, GC should clean it. As you can see, after executing, object `t` wouldn't be unused but GC did nothing with it.

Comment: Almost. When an object is unused, *at some undefined point in the future* the GC will clean it, *if there's actual pressure on memory*.

Comment: Garbage collection can only be efficiently by intentionally delaying the job.  The expensive parts of collection are finding the object roots and compacting the heap, the kind of expense you don't want to pay too often.  It does the job when it has too, not when an object became unused.  Forcing it to do the job early makes it inefficient in more than one way.  You pay that expense for very little gain but you also screw up its ability to do it better in the future.

Comment: @HansPassant Is there a reference that describes how that would 'screw up its ability to do it better in the future'? My system is on a memory-constrained embedded PC, and I'm storing a lot (over 75% of full capacity) of data in `List<>` objects on the heap.  I'd really like to be able to 'dispose' of these and release the memory as soon as possible and would appreciate knowing the best way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dispose never called Garbage Collector automatically, the dispose design to free un-managed resource. The Garbage Collector execution is scheduled processes which will run in after specified time.

When you call .Net Garbage Collector, it calls the Object.Finalize method of an object on garbage collection to free manage resource, that's why your memory use count show less number